# How to call a specific function on FocusChange of all buttons in android?

Tags: android, button, focus

It's possible to specify a particular function to be called when button is clicked by setting its onClick attribute in xml:
                   `android:onClick="function_name"`
I want to do something similar for FocusChange of buttons, is this possible?

Specifically, I wish to increase my button's size when it has focus and make it normal sized when not focussed. To apply this to all my buttons, I hoped to call a specific function which does this and then specify this function name in my style.xml. But there is no onFocusChange attribute in android.

It works when I add overriden onSetFocusChangeListener for each of my buttons separately in the code. But is there any other solution?

Pls help.

-Kiki

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Handling UI Events you need to implement event listeners.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html)

```
// Create an anonymous implementation of OnClickListener
private OnClickListener mCorkyListener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
      // do something when the button is clicked
    }
};
```

You can use the item selector to specify the states of a button:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item android:state_pressed="true"
           android:drawable="@drawable/l_bar_default3" /> <!-- pressed -->
     <item android:state_focused="true"
           android:drawable="@drawable/l_bar_default3" /> <!-- focused -->
     <item android:drawable="@drawable/l_bar_pressed3" /> <!-- default -->
 </selector>
```

Comment: I need to change the ButtonSize when focussed, not clicked. It works when I set the OnFocusChangeListener and inside onFocusChange, I change the button size. But I have to do this separately for each button. Is there a way I can give just one implementation and all my buttons will use this when Focus changes? Is that what you explained as anonymous implementation of OnClickListener?

Comment: yes, use the same structure for View.OnFocusChangeListener. use button.setOnFocusListener(mCorkyListener) to add the listener to a button